# How to solve the Error: No module named 'Section3' while using Pyqt5?

Tags: python, module, pyqt5

I am a beginner in learning pyqt5. when I run the command `from Section3.Dialog import Ui_Dialog` as the tutorial taught, It gave me the Error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Section3'`.
 Any guidance will be appreciated as I have already searched the error in net but have no idea yet.

I watched the tutorial PYQT5 video namely ***"Packtpub Python GUI Programming Recipes using PyQt5 [Video]_git.ir"*** while in the third folder named ***"3. Enhancing the Qt5 GUI Functionality"*** in the file namely ***"11.Calling Dialogs from the Main Window.mp4"*** at the time :***"05:52"*** teacher writes this command `from Section3.Dialog import Ui_Dialog` but when I run it it gave me the error :`from Section3.Dialog import Ui_Dialog`.

Comment: My guess is that Section3 is a user-defined package (for the class).  Section3 is not a standard Python package.  Either that, or there's an earlier `from xxxx import Section3` where xxxx is some package that defines a Section3 module.

Comment: Dear Jeff, I appreciate your answering I have already created a folder namely "Section3", and put the Dialog module in it. It is equal to the command: from Section3.Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python interpreter is looking for a folder called "Section3" located in the same directory as your python script. Inside the 'Section3' folder there needs to be a python script called 'Dialog' which has a class or function called 'Ui_Dialog'. Make sure that the folder 'Section3' exists and is located in the same folder as your script, and it should import just fine.